# How to set location for object using x,y

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I use coordinates (x,y) to change the position of my PictureBox to another place on my form using X and Y description? I'm not sure how to use 'Point' properly.

Comment: Post what you have done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `checkedListSample` be the required object, then we can set it's location by using the following code, with its `X` co ordinate as `200` and `Y` co ordinate as `150`.

```
 checkedListSample.Location = new Point(200, 150);
```

if you want to create a new point means use this snippet:

```
 Point newPoint = new Point(200, 200);
```

then you can also assign this `newPoint` as location.

```
 checkedListSample.Location = newPoint;
```